# Union into new table issue

Tags: ms-access, union

I have these 3 queries. I need the result of the three queries combined and added to a new table called "Overall_Rating". I tried Union them all together which works for viewing the data. However when try a INTO "Overall_Rating" it won't let me because it says it is an action query. How can I add the results of all these queries into one new table?

Here are queries:

```
SELECT ST.pipe_segment_reference,
       IIF(ST.structural_peak > OM.o_m_peak, ST.structural_peak, OM.o_m_peak) AS Overall_Peak,
       ST.structural_score + OM.o_m_score AS Overall_Score,
       ST.structural_defects + OM.o_m_defects AS Overall_Defects,
       ROUND(Overall_Score / Overall_Defects, 1) AS Overall_Index
FROM structural_rating AS ST
INNER JOIN o_m_rating AS OM ON OM.pipe_segment_reference = ST.pipe_segment_reference;

SELECT ST.pipe_segment_reference,
       ST.structural_peak AS Overall_Peak,
       ST.structural_score AS Overall_Score,
       ST.structural_defects AS Overall_Defects,
       ST.structural_index AS Overall_Index
FROM structural_rating AS ST
LEFT JOIN o_m_rating AS OM ON OM.pipe_segment_reference = ST.pipe_segment_reference
WHERE OM.pipe_segment_reference IS NULL;

SELECT OM.pipe_segment_reference,
       OM.o_m_peak AS Overall_Peak,
       OM.o_m_score AS Overall_Score,
       OM.o_m_defects AS Overall_Defects,
       OM.o_m_index AS Overall_Index
FROM o_m_rating AS OM
LEFT JOIN structural_rating AS ST ON OM.pipe_segment_reference = ST.pipe_segment_reference
WHERE ST.pipe_segment_reference IS NULL;
```

Comment: is this access or sql-server?  you have both tagged.

Comment: Will the new table be created in the Access or SQL Server database?

Comment: @db_brad HansUp Sorry ms-access only

Answer (score 1):

Create union query and use it as a base for new make table or append query.